# Insert rule into a SG previously created manually

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I'll explain the scenario:

I've created a cloudformation template with basically this resources:

- serverSG
- serverAutoScallingGroup
- serverLaunchConfig
- serverIAMInstProf
- serverIAMPolicy
- serverIAMRole

The 'serverLaunchConfig' starts AN instance called 'MyServer', this kind instance has a private subnet, and into this subnet there is a NAT server previously created manually.
The cloudformation template is working fine, but the cnf-init doesn't work because my instance security group (serverSG) doesn't have a rule created into NAT security group (natSG) allowing internet access, consequently the 'MyServer' doesn't have internet access.

My problem:

I need to insert a rule into natSG (manually created) allowing serverSG (cloudformation created) access the internet, to perform a correct bootstrap.
Is there any trick to do this (to make it work), or cloudformation is unable to perform this task?

Comment: Are you sure that the Security Group is the cause of the problem? Typically, security groups have all Outbound traffic permitted. If your instance is in a Private Subnet, make sure that the Route Table for the subnet is routing correctly through the NAT server.

Comment: You can edit a Security Group at any time (eg through the console or CLI). Are you saying that you want to make a one-off change, or do you want to modify the CloudFormation template that created the security group?

Answer (score 1):

`cfn-init` is wrong tool here. In order to add a rule to an existing security group, you need to use [AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-ingress.html) for inbound rules and [AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-security-group-egress.html) for outbound rules

`cfn-init` scripts should be used ONLY when you want to do certain customization **inside** the operating system that is running inside your instance. What you wish to do is an interaction with AWS infrastructure and not the Operating system of an instance.